# website upload from camera iphone

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, html

Is it possible to make an upload on website that prompts (as an option) to take a picture from the default camera on the iPhone?

Comment: Do you want to take a new picture, or browse for a current picture?

Comment: Mobile safari iOS 6 allows you upload picture from lib or taken from camera.

Comment: I need to prompt for the camera to actually take the picture and this will upload to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload picture from your picture library or taken by camera on ios 6. It is built in mobile safari. On your server side just do normal way as you usual do.

This [link](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/06/13/ios-6-safari-media-uploads/) will explain How Safari in iOS 6 handles media uploads.

This is screenshoot that taken from real device which is running on iOS6.

[image]

Comment: is it possible to prompt for the camera and after photo is taken to upload it to the server?

Comment: Yes, even video(I'm not sure how big video can be allow).I updated my answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

iPhones don't allow uploads to a website from the browser, either files or photos.

Best bet is a third party app, like http://code.google.com/p/iphone-photo-picker/

Comment: Is it true that iOS5's browser finally allows uploads?

Comment: still, many won't upgrade, as newer IOS versions are slower on old hardware.  Don't expect people to upgrade just to use your site.

Comment: but is it possible for the camera to start to take a photo and upload it to the server once the picture is taken?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to build an app for that I believe there is currently no way for a website to request that.